# read_eager() is not returning output of the executed command

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnet, telnetlib

Am running a example script of telnet lib and observed that the script is printing out on to the console.

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "xxxxxxxxx"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

and the it return nothing
The Target is windows machine and source where the script is executed is linux.

Comment: Did you try to manually telnet to the target machine, and did you control the prompts (I had to change the Password prompt for my BSD machine)?

Comment: Yah i tried manually. Changing password prompt means?

Comment: My system has an additional (variable) string between `Password` and `:`, and no space after the colon. So I had to  use `tn.read_until(":")` before `tn.write(password + "\n")`

Comment: Thanks Ballesta, that helped.